# Quick and memory-saving method to modify huge XML files.

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a huge (~2GB) XML file and I need to add new tags and elements and modify the old ones. The problem is that I design it for Windows tablet PC, so I need to modify it without writing it in temporary file (have a lack of disc space) and without using DOM (lack of RAM). Of course, it's desirable that this process will be rather quick. I've already used StAX but it takes the application 3 minutes to rewrite the file into the temporary one. And it's too long. Any ideas?

Comment: You're not going to get any better than writing to a temporary file and renaming it when done. Redesign your application to not be modifying a 2 GB XML file?

Comment: I agree with Dark Falcon. As a side matter, I don't think there's anything better than StAX for streaming large XML files with Java.